Attention Tensor Shape meaning
While I'm trying to extract Attention from a model, I see that there is a part where the attention changes its shape after matmul() with v (value).
The shape goes from:
attention_probs 2 shape: torch.Size([1, 12, 464, 464])
To:
attention shape: torch.Size([1, 464, 12, 64])
And then rearranged to: torch.Size([464, 768])
The most important question, is what part should I use to visualize the attention of each token to another ?
If you can tell me why, I'd be happy. Especially, if I need to use the part before the matmul(), then I wonder why isn't v included in the attention.
qkv = self.Wqkv(hidden_states)
        qkv = pad_input(qkv, indices, cu_seqlens.shape[0] - 1,
                        max_seqlen_in_batch)  # batch, max_seqlen_in_batch, thd
        qkv = rearrange(qkv,
                        'b s (t h d) -> b s t h d',
                        t=3,
                        h=self.num_attention_heads)
        if self.p_dropout or flash_attn_qkvpacked_func is None:
            # if we have nonzero attention dropout (e.g. during fine-tuning) or no Triton, compute attention in PyTorch
            q = qkv[:, :, 0, :, :].permute(0, 2, 1, 3)  # b h s d
            k = qkv[:, :, 1, :, :].permute(0, 2, 3, 1)  # b h d s
            v = qkv[:, :, 2, :, :].permute(0, 2, 1, 3)  # b h s d
            attention_scores = torch.matmul(q, k) / math.sqrt(
                self.attention_head_size)
            attention_scores = attention_scores + bias
            attention_probs = nn.functional.softmax(attention_scores, dim=-1)
            attention_probs = self.dropout(attention_probs)

            # Before matmul(): Torch.Size([1, 12, 464, 464])
            print(f'BUSA: attention_probs 2 shape: {attention_probs.shape}')

            attention = torch.matmul(attention_probs, v).permute(0, 2, 1,
                                                                 3)  # b s h d
            # After matmul() torch.Size([1, 464, 12, 64])
            print(f'BUSA: attention shape: {attention.shape}')

        else:
            # Triton implementation only supports 0 attention dropout
            convert_dtype = qkv.dtype not in [torch.float16, torch.bfloat16]
            if convert_dtype:
                # Triton implementation only supports fp16 and bf16
            ...
            else:
                attention = flash_attn_qkvpacked_func(qkv, bias)
                print(f'BUSA Triton: attention 2 shape: {attention_probs.shape}')

        # attn_mask is 1 for attend and 0 for don't
        attention = unpad_input_only(attention, torch.squeeze(attn_mask) == 1)

        # Still the same: torch.Size([1, 12, 464, 464])
        print(f'BUSA unpadded final attention shape: {attention_probs.shape}')

        rearranged_attention = rearrange(attention, 'nnz h d -> nnz (h d)')

        # torch.Size([464, 768]) which is [464,12,64]
        print(f'REARRANGED ATTENTION: {rearranged_attention.shape}')

        return rearrange(attention, 'nnz h d -> nnz (h d)')


Extract Attention Probabilities : use attention_probs that has which has the shape [1, 12, 464, 464]
Visualize as Heatmaps : each heatmap corresponds to one attention head
aggregation if you want to do to  visualize the overall attention pattern
label the token along x and y axis of heatmap
